# How to filter relationships results in Laravel Voyager?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, voyager

I am developing an e-commerce website where user can have multiple addresses, and when making an order he should associate an address to that order.

My tables looks like this:
user(id, first_name...)
user_address(id, user_id, Address1...)
orders(id, user_id, address_id...)

The problem is when I try to edit the address for a specific order (from Voyager orders edit page), ALL the user addresses appear in the dropdown. I want only the addresses associated with that specific customer (that made the order) to appear in the dropdown. What should I do?

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't post the relevant code for the form, especially where you select only specific values

Comment: @nbk What code do you mean? It is integrated in the voyager package. I didn't wrote any extra line of code.

Comment: I tried to add a scope to the model but it didn't work